# Child component events call the wrong parent

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-elements

I have 2 instances of the same angular element in the same page:

```
<my-widget id="myWidget" isfullscreen="false"></my-widget>
<my-widget id="myWidget" isfullscreen="true"></my-widget>
```

And in the component my-widget I have another component:

```
<my-dropdown *ngIf="isfullscreen === 'true'" #Dropdown1 [items]="myItems" [afterChange]="afterSelectionChanged1"></my-dropdown>
<my-dropdown *ngIf="isfullscreen === 'false'" #Dropdown2 [items]="myItems" [afterChange]="afterSelectionChanged2"></my-dropdown>
```

When the 2 widgets are shown, and I change something in the dropdown of the second widget, the first widget is affected instead of the second. Why does this happen? How could I fix this?

Comment: Can you please add a minimal reproducable example?

Comment: can not answer without looking at what you have written in "afterSelectionChanged1"